# is there an asp.net images folder size limit

Tags: asp.net, .net

I enable users to upload images to my ASP.NET MVC application.  I store them in an images folder under the web UI folder and in my editor template the images are displayed using the image source tag.  If I were to store the images in a directory which is not part of the application project, then I would have to render the image from the server which will take additional processing since this server is shared between applications on the intranet.

My question is, would there be a folder size limit that I need to account for saving images in a web UI folder or it depends on the disk size allocated to the application?

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no explicit limit to the number of files (or the number of bytes), unless your server has some quota configured for it (and hard disk space / file system limitations, of course).

I'd still use subfolders (perhaps one for each user & month/year combination) so that you don't have a lot of files in a single folder. If your users will upload many, many files, file system access may slow down for that folder and it may affect your response times. (This really means a lot of files, though, it may not be an issue if you store only a few hundred of them.) Using subfolders may help with organizing files better, although that will be hidden behind your web UI.

Answer (score 2):

In NTFS file system -

- Maximum disk size: 256 terabytes
- Maximum file size: 256 terabytes
- Maximum number of files on disk: 4,294,967,295
- Maximum number of files in a single folder: 4,294,967,295

[How NTFS Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28WS.10%29.aspx)